# Send PDF string with phpmailer and mpdf

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, mpdf

I need to send an e-mail with php and a PDF attchment without the file because PDF will be generated by a MPDF script. But when I receive the e-mail, my PDF attachment has the correct number of pages but they are blank.

Here my code:
`Global.JS`

```
$.ajax({
  url: "attachmentPDF.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    "link":link
  },
  success: function( data ){
       pdf = data;
       $.ajax({
         url: "rest.php?request=send_mailEC",
         method: "POST",
         data: {
           "pdf": pdf
       },
       success: function( data ) { [--SOMETHING HERE--] }
       });
  }
)};
```

AttachmentPDF.php has at the end of the file these row:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$content = $mpdf->Output('nome.pdf', 'S');
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
echo $content;</code>
```

And here my rest.php with function for "send_mailEC" request:

```
$filename = 'estrattoConto.pdf';
$content = $_POST['pdf'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setLanguage('it','');

$mail->From = $fromMail;
$mail->FromName = $fromNome;
$mail->addAddress($a);
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $oggetto;
$mail->Body    = $testo;
$mail->addStringAttachment($content, $filename,  'base64', 'application/pdf');

$mail->send();
```

Do you know why I send/receive blank pages?

Thanks

Comment: it wont be anything to do with phpmailer, you need to debug the file creation

Comment: I tried to debug the file creation and it works fine.